Why can't I sign into my Adafruit MQTT account from Android phone, but I can from Emulator using Android Studio App
I am trying to create an app using Android Studio which will log into my Adafruit MQTT account and interact with it.  I have created the app on Xcode and it works fine on both the Simulator and my iPhone.
When using Android studio I have an initial page which presents the user with spaces to enter their Adafruit userName and userKey.  This is then stored on the phone and used to connect on future interactions.
This works fine when in Android Studio using the Emulator but when I install the app on my phone I get a log message
D/com.example.mqttkotlinsample.ClientFragment$onViewCreated$1: Connection failure: Not authorized to connect (5)
Here is the code I am using to connect.
class ConnectFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        var switch = 1
        val appContext = requireContext().applicationContext
        val prefs = appContext.getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE)

        val user = prefs.getString("UserName",null)
        val key = prefs.getString("UserKey",null)
        val switched = prefs.getString("switchKey",null)
        val switch3 =switched.toString()
        //val cameraip = prefs.getString("cameraIP",null)
        if (user == null &&
            key == null) {
            // the key does not exist
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_username).setText("")
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_password).setText("")
        } else {
            // handle the value
            val s1 = "tcp://io.adafruit.com:1883"
            val clientIDFromEditText =
                view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_client_id).text.toString()
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_username).setText(user)
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_password).setText(key)
            //view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_server_uri).setText(cameraip)


            val mqttCredentialsBundle = bundleOf(
                MQTT_SERVER_URI_KEY to s1,
                MQTT_CLIENT_ID_KEY to clientIDFromEditText,
                MQTT_USERNAME_KEY to user,
                MQTT_PWD_KEY to key,
                //MQTT_CAMERAIP_KEY to cameraip
            )


            //PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE

            if (switch3 == "1"){
            findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.action_ConnectFragment_to_ClientFragment,
                mqttCredentialsBundle
            )}

        }



        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_prefill).setOnClickListener {
            // Set default values in edit texts
            //view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_server_uri).setText(MQTT_SERVER_URI)
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_client_id).setText(MQTT_CLIENT_ID)
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_username).setText(MQTT_USERNAME)
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_password).setText(MQTT_PWD)
        }

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_clean).setOnClickListener {
            // Clean values in edit texts




            //view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_server_uri).setText("")
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_client_id).setText("")


        }

        view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton2).setOnClickListener{

            val button1 = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton2)
            if (switch==1) {

                val pwdFromEditText = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_password)
                val cursorPosition: Int = pwdFromEditText.selectionStart
                pwdFromEditText.transformationMethod = HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance()

                pwdFromEditText.setSelection(cursorPosition)
                switch = 2
                button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_see_copy)
            }

            else if (switch == 2){
                val pwdFromEditText = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_password)
                val cursorPosition: Int = pwdFromEditText.selectionStart
                pwdFromEditText.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
                pwdFromEditText.setSelection(cursorPosition)
                switch = 1
                button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.see_copy)
            }
        }

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_connect).setOnClickListener {
            //if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {

            //PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        //}

            val s1 = "tcp://io.adafruit.com:1883"

           // val serverURIFromEditText =
               // view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_server_uri).text.toString()
            val clientIDFromEditText =
                view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_client_id).text.toString()
            val usernameFromEditText =
                view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_username).text.toString()
            val pwdFromEditText =
                view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_password).text.toString()

            val mqttCredentialsBundle = bundleOf(
                MQTT_SERVER_URI_KEY to s1,
                MQTT_CLIENT_ID_KEY to clientIDFromEditText,
                MQTT_USERNAME_KEY to usernameFromEditText,
                MQTT_PWD_KEY to pwdFromEditText,
            //MQTT_CAMERAIP_KEY to serverURIFromEditText
            )

            findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.action_ConnectFragment_to_ClientFragment,
                mqttCredentialsBundle
            )

            //val appContext = requireContext().applicationContext
            //val prefs = appContext.getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editor = prefs.edit()
            editor.putString("UserName", usernameFromEditText)
            editor.putString("UserKey", pwdFromEditText)
            editor.putString("switchKey", "1")
            //editor.putString("cameraIP",serverURIFromEditText)
            editor.apply()



        }
    }

I get no code errors and the log shows that the serverURI is correct as is the username and userKey.  The clientID is left empty as per Adafruit's instructions and as I say it connects using the same app on Emulator.
The only difference I can see is that the Pixel 3 XL physical device is running API 31 and the Emulator is using 33, however I have the settings so it can run on min 30.  The phone is only running Android 12.0 since it cannot be updated any more and the emulator is running Android 13.
I really can't think of what the problem is.  If anyone can think of a solution please let me know.
Here is the full log:
2024-09-17 15:03:59.294 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10259; state: ENABLED
2024-09-17 15:03:59.213 12625-12625/? I/qttkotlinsampl: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2024-09-17 15:03:59.268 12625-12625/? D/ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
2024-09-17 15:03:59.422 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.example.mqttkotlinsample' set to: 'default'
2024-09-17 15:03:59.422 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample V/GraphicsEnvironment: App is not on the allowlist for updatable production driver.
2024-09-17 15:03:59.424 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2024-09-17 15:03:59.425 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2024-09-17 15:03:59.436 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/WM-WrkMgrInitializer: Initializing WorkManager with default configuration.
2024-09-17 15:03:59.509 12625-12675/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 160794467; UID 10259; state: ENABLED
2024-09-17 15:04:00.128 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/qttkotlinsampl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2024-09-17 15:04:00.128 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/qttkotlinsampl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2024-09-17 15:04:00.353 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/com.example.mqttkotlinsample.ClientFragment: LAUNCHED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2024-09-17 15:04:00.680 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/com.example.mqttkotlinsample.ClientFragment: a2.4
2024-09-17 15:04:00.680 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/com.example.mqttkotlinsample.ClientFragment: g1008.00006
2024-09-17 15:04:00.680 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/com.example.mqttkotlinsample.ClientFragment: TRYING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2024-09-17 15:04:00.682 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/com.example.mqttkotlinsample.ClientFragment: FLAG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2024-09-17 15:04:00.682 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/serverURI: tcp://io.adafruit.com:1883
2024-09-17 15:04:00.682 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/clientID: 
2024-09-17 15:04:00.682 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/username: xxxxxx
2024-09-17 15:04:00.682 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/pwd: XXXXXXXXXXX
2024-09-17 15:04:00.758 12625-12680/com.example.mqttkotlinsample I/AdrenoGLES-0: QUALCOMM build                   : 781e7d0, I46ff5fc46f
    Build Date                       : 12/01/20
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.31.04.01
    Local Branch                     : QPR1
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
2024-09-17 15:04:00.758 12625-12680/com.example.mqttkotlinsample I/AdrenoGLES-0: Build Config                     : C P 11.0.1 AArch64
2024-09-17 15:04:00.758 12625-12680/com.example.mqttkotlinsample I/AdrenoGLES-0: Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
2024-09-17 15:04:00.761 12625-12680/com.example.mqttkotlinsample I/AdrenoGLES-0: PFP: 0x016ee190, ME: 0x00000000
2024-09-17 15:04:00.762 12625-12680/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID_from_sysfs:197>: Failed to open /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpu_model
2024-09-17 15:04:00.762 12625-12680/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID:221>: Failed to read chip ID from gpu_model. Fallback to use the GSL path
2024-09-17 15:04:00.770 12625-12680/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/hw-ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
2024-09-17 15:04:00.771 12625-12698/com.example.mqttkotlinsample I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2024-09-17 15:04:00.772 12625-12698/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2024-09-17 15:04:00.774 12625-12698/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/Gralloc4: allocator 4.x is not supported
2024-09-17 15:04:00.774 12625-12698/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/Gralloc3: allocator 3.x is not supported
2024-09-17 15:04:01.449 12625-12707/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/AlarmPingSender: Unregister alarmreceiver to MqttService
2024-09-17 15:04:02.017 12625-12712/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/AlarmPingSender: Unregister alarmreceiver to MqttService
2024-09-17 15:04:02.050 12625-12625/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/com.example.mqttkotlinsample.ClientFragment$onViewCreated$1: Connection failure: Not authorized to connect (5)

I hope someone can help.  If you need more information please let me know.
